# How to extract parameters of normal distribution from squared observations?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, machine-learning, estimation

Suppose I know the random variables follow normal distribution, i.e.,
$X\sim\mathcal(\mu,\sigma^2)$, but I can only observe the square of each sample $X^2_i$. How could I extract the parameters of $\mu$ and $\sigma$. I am thinking of moment matching, but it is unclear to me how to proceed. Anybody can help?

Comment: Does it help that your distribution has a name? Well, square root of your sample. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution

Comment: Multiple of a non-central chi-squared distribution. See Wikipedia if you're not familiar with it. That may help.

Comment: There is a table of the non central moments of the normal distribution in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution .  You can estimate the 2nd, 4th, 6th, etc n.c. moments from the data by using $\sum_i X_i^2/n$, and so on. Equating the formulas to the empirical moments gives you simultaneous polynomial equations in $\mu^2$ and $\sigma^2$. Note you will be unable to ever learn the sign of $\mu$ from such data, but by using the 2nd and 4th moment formulas you should be able to estimate $\mu^2$ and $\sigma^2$.